# Pandas: Compare next column value with previous column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame structure with example data:

```
        Col1   Col2     Col3
        1         1      8
        5         4      7
        3         9      9
        1         NaN    NaN
```

Columns have a sequential ordering, meaning Col1 comes before Col2 and so on...
I want to compare if two (or more) subsequent columns have the same value. If so I want to drop the entire row. NaN values can appear but should not be treated as having the same value

So with the rows above, I'd like to have row 1 and 3 dropped (row 1: Col1->Col2 same value, row 3: Col2 -> Col3 same value) and row 2 and 4 to be kept in the dataframe.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) and filter rows if exist no `0` value per rows by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) for not equal and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if all `True` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.diff(axis=1).ne(0).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Col3
1     5   4.0   7.0
3     1   NaN   NaN
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.diff(axis=1))
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0   NaN   0.0   7.0
1   NaN  -1.0   3.0
2   NaN   6.0   0.0
3   NaN   NaN   NaN

print (df.diff(axis=1).ne(0))
   Col1   Col2   Col3
0  True  False   True
1  True   True   True
2  True   True  False
3  True   True   True

print (df.diff(axis=1).ne(0).all(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```